# Are the criteria for which questions is a duplicate of which based on date of posting or quality of answers?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, close-reasons

As an example, this 2011 question:

[setTimeout with zero delay used often in web pages, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4574940/settimeout-with-zero-delay-used-often-in-web-pages-why/4575011#4575011)

was marked as duplicate of this 2009 one:

[Why is setTimeout(fn, 0) sometimes useful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/779379/why-is-settimeoutfn-0-sometimes-useful)

However, in my opinion (admittedly biased, as I wrote the answer to #1), the later question had a MUCH better set of answers (the second question's main accepted answer is actually somewhat wrong, as per the highly voted comment under it. It has 1 good answer with 7 upvotes, and another which would have been good except it's merely a link with no content).

**Is there any reason why the first question was closed as a dupe and not the second, given the relative answer quality? Was it merely the date of posting?**

Answer (score 1):

If you feel that a question closed as a duplicate is of higher quality, or has more value in its answers, then just flag the question and ask a moderator to reverse the duplicate closing.  Getting a bunch of non-mods to try to do it is generally more work than its worth.  If a mod agrees that the "duplicate" should be the canonical question, they can reverse it easily enough.

If both questions have valuable answers then it would be better to merge the questions, rather than closing one as a duplicate of the other.  Just flag the question and ask a moderator to merge the two questions.  The moderator will decide which should be merged into which, although if you feel strongly that one question is better, by all means suggest that in the flag text.

As with anything, if the flag is declined or not acted on as you would like, you're free to come to meta to discuss the moderator's response, and why you feel some other action should have been taken instead.

Comment: I agree with your logic, but I don't know enough about the rules (thus my question) to be sure that the mod would **care** about the quality. I'd rather not add to mod workload by raising false flags

Comment: @DVK They would.  (Or at least, they should.)  It is entirely appropriate to say that the duplicate target should instead be the one closed as a duplicate.  That said, given that both questions appear to have a number of good (or at least highly upvoted) answers, it probably would qualify for merging.

Comment: ... basically, that was my polite way of letting you know that you didn't actually answer my real question, which is whether the rule for duple closing is date based or quality based or moderator mood based :)

Comment: @DVK It was implicit in the answer.  If it wouldn't be an appropriate flag, then I wouldn't post an answer telling you to flag for that reason.  That I'm suggesting flagging means that flagging for this reason would be appropriate.  Also note that most questions (including this question) aren't closed by moderators, but rather by regular users with sufficient rep.

Comment: ah. Mind editing that in as explicit one? Since the rest of your answer (flag for the mods to achieve reversal of closing or merge) is something I already know about :)